# Conditional probability with cherry seeds

Tags: probability

A bowl contains seven cherries, exactly four of which have had their seeds removed.
(a). A pig eats two quickly without commenting on the presence or absence of seeds.
Determine the probability pj that the pig consumed j cherries without seeds
(j = 0, 1, 2).

(b) Subsequently a cherry is picked at random from the remaining five.
(i) What is the probability that this cherry contains a seed
(ii) Given that the cherry contains a seed, what is the probability that the pig
consumed only cherries without seeds?

So part (a) am I right in assuming that when Pr(j=0)=0 and Pr(j=1)=4/7, would it also mean that Pr(j=2)=4/7 since there is no information about what was in the cherries the pig ate?

Part (b) (i) again i feel as though since there was no information on the already consumed cherries, the odds may be 4/5, but am unsure of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

a)

> $j(0)$ would be $\frac 47\times\frac36=\frac27$ 
> $j(1)$ would be harder to calculate, so let's go to $j(2)$ for now. 
> $j(2)$ would be  $\frac 37\times\frac26=\frac17$
> $j(1)$ would now be $1-\frac27-\frac17=\frac47$

b)

> i)
>
> > Do casework.
> >  $\frac 27\times\frac 35=\frac6{35}$ 
> >  $\frac17\times\frac15=\frac1{35}$
> >  $\frac47\times\frac25=\frac8{35}$ 
> >  $\frac6{35}+\frac1{35}+\frac8{35}=\frac37$
>
> ii)
>
> > More casework.

Comment: I understand j(1), however could you clarify j(0) and j(2)? I assumed since no cherries have been picked, the odds of getting one with a seed would just be 0?

Comment: j(0) doesn't mean 0 cherries are picked, it just means that the pig ate $0$ cherries without seeds.

Comment: ahh thank you! That makes a lot more sense now

Comment: No casework is required.  (It works, but is not needed).

Answer (score 0):

> > (a). A pig eats two quickly without commenting on the presence or absence of seeds. Determine the probability pj that the pig consumed j cherries without seeds (j = 0, 1, 2).
>
> So part (a) am I right in assuming that when Pr(j=0)=0 and Pr(j=1)=4/7, would it also mean that Pr(j=2)=4/7 since there is no information about what was in the cherries the pig ate?

No, $p_j\neq 0$ because it is clearly possible to select none of the seeded cherries.

You want $p_j$ to be the probability for selecting $j$ from $3$ seeded cherries *and* $2-j$ from $4$ seedless cherries, when selecting any $2$ from all $7$ cherries.

PS: Have you encountered the binomial coefficient yet?  $\binom nk$ or ${}^n\mathrm C_k$.

> > (b) Subsequently a cherry is picked at random from the remaining five. (i) What is the probability that this cherry contains a seed
>
> Part (b) (i) again i feel as though since there was no information on the already consumed cherries, the odds may be 4/5, but am unsure of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

There were *three* seeded cherries among the *seven* that were in the bowl, any one of them may equally well have been the cherry you picked.   As you said, the consumption of two cherries gives no information about the probability.

Randomly arrange seven such cherries in a line, say that the pig ate the first two cherries and you picked the third.   What is the probability that this third cherry is one from the three that have seeds?

*Reality check:* Determine the probability that the cherry is one from the *four* seedless *by the same method*.   Adding that to your answer should give $1$.

> > (ii) Given that the cherry contains a seed, what is the probability that the pig consumed only cherries without seeds?

You want the probability that the pig selected $0$ from the $2$ seeded cherries *that you did not (later) pick*, *and* $2-j$ from $4$ seedless cherries, when selecting any $2$ from the $6$ cherries *which you did not pick*.